# Contenteditable and jQuery: avoid div

Tags: jquery

When the user press enter in a contentEditable div it generates divs. How can I avoid this and create p or/and br ? (Please, only jQuery)

here to play and check: http://jsfiddle.net/r4gaftj2/

jQuery:

```
$('#input').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) { // if press enter
            // alert('You pressed enter!'); //it works

            // it does not work:
            // e.preventDefault();
            // $('#input').append("<br>"); 
            // $(this).html('<br><br>');
        }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="input" contenteditable="true"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit complicated but works.

Native object sometimes don't have toString implementation and returns nil. That's why you have nothing in alert. Instead of alert please use console.info.

```
$('#input').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        // Get current cursor position
        // This is section object
        var s = window.getSelection();
        // Get range object, this object gives you
        // possibility to add new elements after cursor position.
        var range = s.getRangeAt( 0 );
        e.preventDefault();
        // creating initial br
        var last = document.createElement('br');
        // Initial br
        range.insertNode( last );
        // Parent container (editable node)
        var container = s.focusNode;
        // If cursor is inside text container will be text node, need to pull up.
        if ( container.nodeType != HTMLElement.ELEMENT_NODE )
            container = container.parentNode;
        if ( last == container.children.item( container.children.length-1 ) && last.previousSibling && last.previousSibling.nodeType == HTMLElement.ELEMENT_NODE ) {
            // After BR was other element node so it\s safety to add only one BR.
        } else if ( !last.previousSibling || last.previousSibling.nodeType == HTMLElement.TEXT_NODE || (last.nextElementSibling && last.nextElementSibling.tagName != 'BR') ) {
            // If first node: to see new line need br and something and this can't be text node...
            // If next isn't BR need to create second to see new line (see above)
            last = document.createElement('br');
            range.insertNode( last );
        }
        // Cleanup cursor
        s.removeAllRanges();
        // move cursor after last added node
        range.setStartAfter( last );
        range.setEndAfter( last );
        // set new cursor position
        s.addRange( range );
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not understand your code. Can you explain? If I make an alert of s or range it gives me nothing

Comment: If you make enter, the cursor do not go the the next line. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/r4gaftj2/1/ I suppose it is because the preventDevault

Comment: Thank you for the efford. This is quite close. Why do you need two br if the container is empty?